Internationalization i18n in spring is not working i receive ??greeting_en_US?
I'm following this instruction https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization
In the page is getting displayed ??greeting_en_US?? instead of Hello! Welcome to our website!
My code is
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver;

import java.util.Locale;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return slr;
    }
    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lci.setParamName("lang");
        return lci;
    }
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

    }


message.properties
greeting=Hello! Welcome to our website!
lang.change=Change the language
lang.eng=English
lang.fr=French

message_fr.properties
greeting=Bonjour! Bienvenue sur notre site!
lang.change=Changez la langue
lang.eng=Anglais
lang.fr=Francais

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>index</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 th:text="#{greeting}"></h1>
<span th:text="#{lang.change}"></span>:
<select id="locales">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="en" th:text="#{lang.eng}"></option>
    <option value="fr" th:text="#{lang.fr}"></option>
</select>
</body>
</html>

It should be working be it is not working. Obviously I'm missing something. When I'm creating the project I add Dependencies

Spring Web
Spring Data JPA
MySQL Driver
Thymeleaf

